# Batching Records with kafka template

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a java server side application that listens on tcp connection ,reads message ,process and  publish to kafka topic. We use a transactional kafka template with kafka tm to achieve once only semantics.This works fine when we are commiting record by record.We would want to commit a batch of records either based on an  event (check if the message has a certain parameter set,then commit) or based on a time interval. Is this something that is possible with kafka template.We use spring kafka 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

You can run the `KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction()` on a different thread and hand off the requests from the TCP listener via a `BlockingQueue` or similar, with the queue being `poll()`ed within the scope of the callback (probably with a timeout).

Then, when the right condition applies; exit the callback to commit the transaction, then start another one.

Comment: Thanks Gary .Are there plans in  roadmap to add kafkaTemplate.batchSend() where you  can configure the batch size  for a commit.If I read the document right this feature exist when using the KafkaMessageListenerContainer and then publish to a topic.I can open a feature request if this makes sense.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; Kafka already provides a batching mechanism via the producer `linger.ms` property. If you mean you want to send a collection to the template, you can write a simple wrapper around the template. I don't think we want to pollute the API with a `batchSend()` for every `send()` overload.

Comment: If  I am using a transactional producer using kafka template with an @ Transactional on send method,even though the producer uses the linger.ms/batch.size  to batch the records across the network,wouldn't that still create n transactions if the batch has n records which i guess is expensive.May be I will have to write the wrapper to pass a list to kafkaTemplate.

Comment: Either way, you have to do the batching within the transaction.